# Simulate a deadlock in mariadb

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have an application that I'm using to query data's from the db. This application has a field to put an SQL query like:

```
SELECT number, message FROM test_table WHERE number > ?
```

What I want to check, is how this application behave in case of a deadlock. So, my question is how can I simulate a deadlock for the SELECT query to be the deadlock victim? What should I run to make this happen?

I'm using this table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_table` (
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` datetime DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `message` text DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I tried to make a deadlock using two different transactions like this, but they were deadlocking each other, not the SELECT query that I wanted:

T1:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO test_table (message) SELECT 'test'
SLEEP(5);
UPDATE test_table SET message = 'foo';
COMMIT;
```

T2:

```
START TRANSACTION;
UPDATE test_table SET message = 'foo';
SLEEP(5);
INSERT INTO test_table (message) SELECT 'test'
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Try changing your SELECT statement to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE WAIT 1`.

Comment: A SELECT will lock rows if it includes a `FOR UPDATE` clause.